# function is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to organize my code using revealing module pattern but I got myComponent is not a function error. Hmm what's wrong?

```
var canva = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var myComponent = function(canva) {

    var init = function() {
        console.log('init');
    };


    return {
        init:init
    };

}(canvas);

myComponent(canva).init();
```

Comment: `function(canva){` is an IIFE which returns an Object with a single property, init, which is a function ... note that this means myComponent is the object returned, not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this syntax :

```
var myComponent = function(canva){
   //function body  
 }(canvas);
```

However, you have to not call the function after decalring it , so , you have to use the following syntax instead :

```
var myComponent = function(canva){
   //function body  
 }// remove : (canvas);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either initialize the function with canvas by default or provide it as a param, but not both.

```
  var canva = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var myComponent = function(canva){

  var init = function(){
    console.log('init')
  }


  return{
    init:init
  }

}(canva);

myComponent.init();
```

(this variant is useful if your component's consumers/clients do not need to configure the used canvas/dependency)

or

```
var canva = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var myComponent = function(canva){

  var init = function(){
    console.log('init')
  }


  return{
    init:init
  }

};

myComponent(canva).init();
```

(this variant is useful if your component's consumers/clients need to provide their own parameterized/custom dependency to your component)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var myComponent = function(canva){

      var init = function(){
        console.log('init')
      }


      return{
        init:init
      }

    };
```

// and use it as

```
 myComponent(null).init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it's a parser problem and you need to wrap self-invoking functions with parentheses (see code below)

> When the parser encounters the function keyword in the global scope or
>   inside a function, it treats it as a function declaration (statement),
>   and not as a function expression, by default. If you don’t explicitly
>   tell the parser to expect an expression, it sees what it thinks to be
>   a function declaration without a name and throws a SyntaxError
>   exception because function declarations require a name.

Credit for the exact wording above goes to: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

```
var myComponent = (function(canva) {

  var init = function() {
    console.log('init');
  };

  return {
    init:init
  };

})(canvas);

var canva = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
myComponent.init();
```

Also, change `myComponent(canva).init();` to `myComponent.init();`. `myComponent` is not a function.